# Get Current Row Number From CollectionView DataTemplate Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a  with <CollectionView.ItemTemplate> with  and I would like to display the current row number of each one.  Is it possible and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is to just add an Index property to the Item your binding the item templates to and fill that index from the ViewModel. Templates will be reused, so the template used at index 0 can later appear at index 10 etc.